# screenrecording and screenshot detector

Tags: applications, samsung, system

Is there a way or an app or anything to detect whether the other person is screen recording or screenshotting their screen while engaging with you with either mobile or PC?

Comment: The app in foreground on the other party's side needs to have this functionality built in. There is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: In many apps there is a cast notification icon when they record the screen. And screen recording can be done by adb too.. maybe it's recorded in the logs(not sure.. idk much about how adb works)